# Installing FFI-Platypus on Strawberry perl 5.28.1

Tags: perl, ffi, strawberry-perl

When I am trying to install [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) on straweberry perl 5.28.1 I get the below messsage. Any idea what might be wrong?

```
xs/windl.o:windl.c:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules'
xs/windl.o:windl.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameExA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [Makefile:529: blib\arch\auto\FFI\Platypus\Platypus.xs.dll] Error 1
  PLICEASE/FFI-Platypus-0.86.tar.gz
  "C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\c\bin\gmake.exe" -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'FFI::Platypus'.
Failed during this command:
 PLICEASE/FFI-Platypus-0.86.tar.gz            : make NO
```

also here are the linker steps on the installation

```
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include \
-s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2 \
  -DVERSION=\"0.86\" \
-DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   lib/FFI/Platypus.c -o lib/FFI/Platypus.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/closure.c -o xs/closure.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/complex.c -o xs/complex.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/custom.c -o xs/custom.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/havepm.c -o xs/havepm.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/meta.c -o xs/meta.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/names.c -o xs/names.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/perl_math_int64.c -o xs/perl_math_int64.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/record_opaque.c -o xs/record_opaque.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/record_simple.c -o xs/record_simple.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/record_string.c -o xs/record_string.o
gcc -c  -Iinclude -IC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../include -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.86\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.86\"  "-IC:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE"   xs/windl.c -o xs/windl.o
"C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"FFI::Platypus\", 'DLBASE' => 'Platypus', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => [], 'FILE' => q[lib/FFI/Platypus]);"
g++.exe lib/FFI/Platypus.def -o blib\arch\auto\FFI\Platypus\Platypus.xs.dll -LC:/Dev/OPENSO~1/Perl/STRAWB~1.1-6/c/lib/PKGCON~1/../../lib/../lib -mdll -s -L"C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\c\lib" lib/FFI/Platypus.o xs/closure.o xs/complex.o xs/custom.o xs/havepm.o xs/meta.o xs/names.o xs/perl_math_int64.o xs/record_opaque.o xs/record_simple.o xs/record_string.o xs/windl.o   "C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\lib\CORE\libperl528.a" "C:\Dev\OPENSO~1\Perl\STRAWB~1.1-6\c\lib\PKGCON~1\..\..\lib\..\lib\libffi.a" -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
```

Comment: `EnumProcessModules` and `GetModuleFileNameExA` are Windows API functions. I'm guessing from the API documentation that `-lKernel32` is missing from the linker command line. The linker command line is unfortunately not visible in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the linker error message (missing symbols `EnumProcessModules` and `GetModuleFileNameExA` which are Windows API functions) it is clear that the library `kernel32` is missing. The linker command line shown in your update proves that.

The update also shows that you have installed Strawberry Perl under a path that contains spaces:

```
"C:\Dev\OpenSource Tools\Perl\strawberry-perl-5.28.1.1-64bit-portable\...
```

Using paths with characters that have special meanings, like space (), hash (`#`), etc., is always asking for trouble. In this particular case it leads to a build that can't find any libraries:

```
...
Configuring FFI-Platypus-0.86 ... using system libffia via PkgConfigPP
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lpsapi
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmoldname
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lkernel32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luser32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgdi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinspool
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomdlg32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -ladvapi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lshell32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lole32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -loleaut32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lnetapi32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luuid
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lws2_32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmpr
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinmm
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lversion
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbc32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbccp32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomctl32
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
...
```

Unfortunately the warning is not "mostly harmless", because it leads to a linker command line without e.g. `-lkernel32` and hence the linker error.

**Solution**: rename the directories in the path to remove any spaces, e.g.

```
C:\Dev\OpenSource_Tools\...
```

---

**Original answer** The github project for [FFI::Platypus](https://github.com/Perl5-FFI/FFI-Platypus) shows that the author is running a [CI build for Strawberry Perl](https://github.com/Perl5-FFI/FFI-Platypus/blob/master/.appveyor.yml). So one thing to check would be to follow the build instructions in that CI build:

```
cpanm Capture::Tiny ExtUtils::MakeMaker ExtUtils::ParseXS IPC::Cmd
cpanm FFI::Platypus
```

You might also want to compare your build log to one of the [FFI::Platypus CI Builds on AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/plicease/ffi-platypus/builds/23013891/job/402o0v2hcaux7l9p?fullLog=true) to discover differences.

Comment: Just tried on my Windows 10 64-bit VM: (a) download & unpack Strawberry Perl 5.28.1.1 portable zip file, (b) opened `portableshell` and (c) entered the two command lines from my solution. Module build goes through without a hitch and `perl -MFFI::Platypus -e 1` runs without error message afterwards.

Comment: I tried the instructions but still get the same error , i added more info about the installation if you want to look thanks .

Comment: I've now verified that the space in the path name is the cause for your error. I've updated my answer accordingly. I would suggest to always use `cpanm -v ...` in the future and checking for warnings in the output.